How to add single quotation at the start and end of each word in a line in linux
I have list of strings in line delimited by space as below.
Hello how are you

And this needs to be changed to below,
‘Hello’, ‘how’, ‘are’, ‘you’


We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Do you REALLY want to add smart quotes (‘how’) instead of ASCIII text quotes ('how' or "how" or maybe even \how``) around your words? YMMV with what any other tool does with the output if so.

There is a straightforward way to do this with awk:
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\047, \047"}{$1=$1;print "\047" $0 "\047" }' file


BEGIN{OFS="\047, \047"}: The BEGIN block is executed before processing any lines from the input file. OFS stands for Output Field Separator. By setting OFS="\047, \047", we tell awk to use ', ' as the separator between fields when using the print statement or when the main record is being rebuilt.
{$1=$1; print "\047" $0 "\047"}: This is the main processing block that operates on each line of the input file.

$1=$1: This is a trick to force awk to rebuild the entire record $0. When we reassign a value to one of the fields (in this case, $1), awk rebuilds $0 using the current value of OFS as the separator between fields.
print "\047" $0 "\047": This prints the rebuilt record $0, enclosed in single quotes.




It’s not working for me.. just giving output as -ksh

You need \047 instead of the literal single quotes. The desired output also has a space after each comma. awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\047, \047"}{$1=$1;print "\047" $0 "\047" }'

@tripleee yea, totally forgot about that. Done

This might be done using GNU sed following way, using RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK as stipulated by desired output
echo "Hello how are you" | sed -e "s/ /’, ‘/g" -e "s/^/‘/" -e "s/$/‘/"

gives output
‘Hello’, ‘how’, ‘are’, ‘you‘

Explanation: I instruct GNU sed to do 3 things: substitute space using ’, ‘ globally, substitute start of line (^) using ‘, substitute end of line ($) using ‘. Note that there is never more than 1 start of line and 1 end of line per line, so no global modifier is needed.
(tested in GNU sed 4.8)

This is completely portable to POSIX sed, there is nothing which is specific to GNU sed (though some legacy versions might choke on non-ASCII quotes; maybe try LC_ALL=C if yours doesn't accept this script directly; or fall back to Perl, which supports a souped-up vocabulary).
